# Surjective morphism of affine varieties and dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to do the following exercise from the book *An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry*:

> Show that if $X \to Y$ is a surjective morphism of affine algebraic varieties, then the dimension of $X$ is at least as large as the dimension of $Y$.

Could anyone give me a hint? I'm looking for a proof that avoids commutative algebra since it is not mentionned in the book at this point.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let $f:X\to Y$ be your morphism of algebraic varieties over the  field $k$.
a) By considering the restricted mapping $f^{-1}(Y_i) \to Y_i$ where $Y_i\subset Y$ is an irreducible component of maximal dimension , you reduce to the case where $Y$ is irreducible .

b) If $X_j$ are the finitely many irreducible components of $X$, you have
$Y=\bigcup f(X_j)$, hence $Y=\bigcup \overline {f(X_j)}$, so that one of the $f(X_j)$ is dense in $Y$.
In other words by considering $f_{\big|X_j}: X_j\to Y $ you reduce to the case that $X$ is irreducible **but** you must weaken yout hypothesis to *$f$ is dominant* (that is with dense image) instead of *$f$ is surjective*. Don't worry : we'll still manage!

c) Since the  morphism $f:X\to Y$  of irreducible varieties is dominant, it induces a morphism of the corresponding function fields $f^* :\operatorname{Rat}(Y) \to \operatorname{Rat}(X) $  .
This implies by pure algebra (field theory!) the  inequality on transcendence degrees over $k$ : $$\operatorname{trdeg}_k (\operatorname{Rat}(Y))\leq \operatorname{trdeg}_k (\operatorname{Rat}(X))    \quad (*)$$
d) Finally, for an irreducible variety $Z$, we know that $\dim (Z)=\operatorname{trdeg}_k (\operatorname{Rat} (Z)$  (this is essentially a corollary of Noether's normalization theorem). If you take this into account,  $(*)$ yields the required inequality $$ \dim(Y)\leq \dim(X)      \quad  (**)  $$

**Edit** The above works for all algebraic varieties, affine or not. Actually I hadn't even noticed that the OP  mentioned *affine* varieties when I answered the question!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm surprised that this question was in the first chapter of the book, but at least I won't lose my time trying to find an elementary solution.

Comment: Dear @Math536, yes this is surprising. Of course, I can't prove that there is no elementary solution, but I would be very surprised if there were. Given the numerous extremely competent users on this site, I suggest  that if no elementary solution is mentioned here within a few hours, we  declare the question settled :-)

Comment: Does this result fail if we replace "affine variety" with "Noetherian space" and "morphism" with "continuous map"?

Comment: Given that $Y$ is irreducible, why doesn't $Y=\bigcup f(X_j)$ imply that $Y = f(X_j)$ for some $X_j$?

Comment: @Jon:  No, because you don't know that each $f(X_j)$ is closed. Think of the decomposition  $\mathbb P^1=\mathbb A^1\cup \{\infty\}$ with $\mathbb P^1$ irreducible.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I see, thanks!

Comment: I believe there is a typo in inequality (*) and should read as $\text{trdeg}_k(\text{Rat}(Y)) \le \text{trdeg}_k(\text{Rat}(X))$.

Comment: @kindasorta. You are right and I have corrected that typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of dimension involving chains of subvarieties. Now, you can assume, without loss of generality, that both X and Y are irreducible (do you see why?). Induction on the dimension of Y should give it to you then.

Comment: I can prove that if the statement is true for $Y$ of dimension $d$, then it is true for $Y$ of dimension $d+1$ and $X$ irreducible. The problem is that I don't see why you can assume $X$ is irreducible.

Comment: If Y is irreducible, then one of the images of the irreducible components of X must contain an open (and thus dense) subset of Y, so you can throw away the rest of Y and the rest of X.

Comment: I should like to emphasize that just using the definition of dimension will not even begin to scratch the problem. You have to make use of the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are algebraic varieties and invoke some  non trivial results from commutative algebra/algebraic geometry . Like Chevalley's difficult theorem implicit in Brooke's comment, without which it is not at all clear why the image of an irreducible component of $X$  should contain an open subset of $Y$.